# Assertion failed (blockSize % 2 == 1 && blockSize > 1) in cv::adaptiveThreshold

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to do an adaptive threshold:

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::imread(inputFile);
cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::adaptiveThreshold(mat, mat, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 20, 0);
cv::imwrite(outputFile, mat);
```

But it fails with this message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (blockSize % 2 == 1 && blockSize > 1) in cv::adaptiveThreshold, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp, line 797
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that I was putting an even value for blockSize, while it required only odd values, so changing it from 20 to 21 fixed the assert failure:

```
cv::adaptiveThreshold(mat, mat, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 21, 0);
```

[The docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) kind of mention it, but they are not explicit it will fail if blockSize is not odd:

> blockSize – Size of a pixel neighborhood that is used to calculate a threshold value for the pixel: 3, 5, 7, and so on.

As you can see, nowhere does it say "it will fail if blockSize is not odd".

Comment: A 20x20 neighborhood for a pixel is necessarily asymmetrical. It's understandable why that's forbidden. W.r.t. your last line, **all** functions might fail if you pass them invalid paramaters. It would be excessive to repeat that statement 10.000 times for all parameters of all functions in OpenCV. For instance, it's also not stated that blockSize should be smaller than your image. That said, OpenCV documentation is not the best. Good libraries state how image edges behave.